# File Explorer in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

Can anyone tell where the file explorer is located in Android Studio?

I tried to search in windows menu but there isn't any option like "show view" that used to be in Eclipse.

Comment: Please change the accepted answer to [Codeversed's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17628670/file-explorer-in-android-studio/44203922#44203922). It's the correct method in Android Studio 3.

Answer (score 156, accepted):

You can start Android Device Monitor from the Android Studio (green robot icon on the toolbar, to the left of the help icon). From the ADM, select the device/emulator, then select the File Explorer tab.

Comment: Maybe they also have a built-in DDMS perspective as they do in Eclipse, but I couldn't find it.

Comment: NOTE: For me, clicking on the Device Monitor first popped up a window asking for the location of the SDK. This was located at C:\users\<USER>\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\ . After putting in the correct SDK it worked.

Comment: For me, when I'm using a real device I need to disconnect and connect again in order to ADM recognize it.

Comment: Outdated in 2018

Comment: The green robot icon has disappeared. Thank you Google for making our live difficult.

Answer (score 93):

**Android Studio 3 Canary 1** has a new **Device File Explorer**

View -> Tool Windows -> Device File Explorer

So much better than DDMS and is the new improved way to get files off of your device!

Allows you to 'Open', 'Save As', 'Delete', 'Synchronize' and 'Copy Path'. Pretty awesome stuff!

[image: Android Studio 3 Canary 1 - Device File Explorer]

Comment: For those wondering where to find it (as I did for some time). Bottom right corner, vertical icon. https://imgur.com/PXKLA7x

Comment: Good one and up to date. Should probably be marked as the correct one now.

Comment: View -> Tool Windows -> Device File Explorer

Comment: Does anyone have a clue on what to do if there is no Device File Explorer in View -> Tool Windows and none in the bottom right corner?

Comment: I found that I needed to install the Command Line Tools before Device File Explorer would appear in the expected locations

Answer (score 79):

[image]

Then the Android Device Monitor window will pop up. Click on the emulator & File Explorer.

Shared Preference files should be in:

DDMS-> File Explorer ->data -> data -> MY_PACKAGE_NAME -> shared_prefs -> YOUR_PREFERENCE_NAME.xml

[image]

Comment: I am unable to get into /data. When I open it I get an empty folder.  Permission?

Comment: It is possible to open the files that I there. I could not find a way to say access preferences.xml from my application to show it's contents.

Comment: Click on the top right floppy disk picture with the red arrow going through it. Next to the red minus symbol.

Comment: There's no robot icon any more so thank you for that.

Comment: Screenshots were very helpful, especially as a beginner. Thanks!

Comment: Back in the day you didn't need to root your android phone in order to see the SharedPreference file. Now, I think you do. I would recommend actually rooting your phone via a tool like Kingo Root or download an Android Emulator that you can root. For example NOX emulator can be rooted.

Comment: Outdated in 2018

Answer (score 37):

it has changed and its docked to the right bottom of your android studio by default.

[image]

if you dont have that you can open it through view -> tool windows -> device file explorer

[image]

Comment: Thanks for `View > Tool Windows > Device File Explorer`.

Answer (score 27):

This works on Android Studio 1.x:

- Tools --> Android --> Android Device Monitor (this open the ADM)
- Window --> Show View
- Search for File Explorer then press the OK Button
- The File Explorer Tab is now open on the View

Answer (score 12):

`Android Device Monitor` is a part of **ANDROID SDK**.

You can found it here: `C:\android-sdk\tools\lib\monitor-x86\monitor.exe` or `C:\android-sdk\tools\lib\monitor-x86_64\monitor.exe`.

Run it for monitring or exploring files on the AVD.

Answer (score 4):

[Additional stuff to Gene's answer]

If we want to view the "com.google.android.gcm.xml"  file we have to pull out the file from emulator.For that go to top right side of the panel there is button(floppy disk and arrow) for this operation.

[image: Pull a file from the device]

Then we can give the location to save the file.You can open it from any text editor and you will be able to view the content of the XML file.

Answer (score 4):

Android 3.4.1 > Top Menu > View > Tools Window > Device File Manager

Answer (score 4):

I am in Android 3.6.1, and the way " Top Menu > View > Tools Window > Device File Manager"
doesn't work.Because there is no the "Device File Manager" option in Tools Window.

But I resolve the problem with another way:

1、Find the magnifier icon on the top right toobar.
[image]

2、Click it and search "device" in the search bar, and you can see it.
[image]

Answer (score 3):

It is very Simple brother 
Click on the Android Device monitor(ADM) just below the Help menu
then the on ADM select your file explorer from left screen menu
or for more details [go 
here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/e14021/know-where-database-is-stored-in-android-studio/)
 It may Help U thanx

Answer (score 3):

As of Android Studio 2.4 Preview, it seems that they introduced "Device File Explorer" directly into the IDE, so we can finally say goodbye to DDMS. You can enable it from the menu under "View >> Tool Windows".

Answer (score 2):

Refer [Here](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/device-file-explorer.html)

With Android Studio, you may use Android file explorer like:
Click View > Tool Windows > Device File Explorer or click the Device File Explorer

Answer (score 1):

1- menu,  "Tools" -> "Android" -> "DDMS (monitor included)"
2- Open the File Explorer tab.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is looking for the Android Studio (2.3.1) on Mac OSX (10.12.1) answer then here are the steps for it.

> 1. Tools Menu > Android > Android Device Monitor
> 2. Choose Your Device (at Left) > Click on File Explorer Tab (at Right)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

**Device Explorer path for Emulator in Mac**

```
/Users/"UserName"/Documents/AndroidStudio/DeviceExplorer/...
```

**Logs File path for Emulator in Mac**

```
/Users/"UserName"/Documents/AndroidStudio/DeviceExplorer/"EmulatorName"/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.app.domain/files/LogFiles/
```

**Shared Preferences File path for Emulator in Mac**

```
/Users/"UserName"/Documents/AndroidStudio/DeviceExplorer/"EmulatorName"/data/data/com.app.domain/shared_prefs/
```

Answer (score -1):

Do you mean Project Explorer? Click 'Project' tab on the left edge of Android Studio.

Comment: No @marmelade, I meant file explorer. I wanted to open SDCard.

Comment: Consider commenting for asking questions..!

Answer (score -2):

If you want the basic answer to have the files on the left-hand side, just go on "View" then "Tool Buttons", you will then be able to choose "project".