# Android Studio 1.1.0 file explorer

Tags: android, android-studio

Hi guys I'm having troubles to find the file explorer in the new version and there is no perspective like in eclipse.

[File Explorer in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17628670/file-explorer-in-android-studio) is from a previous version of Android Studio

Thanks and regards.

[image]

Comment: Do you mean you want to see the files inside your emulator ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [File Explorer in Android Studio](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17628670/file-explorer-in-android-studio)

Comment: this is the Android Device Monitor in Android Studio and the file explorer tab should be there but is not.

Comment: In the other thread that you are pointing out the instructions are the following: You can start Monitor from the Android Studio (green robot icon on the toolbar, to the left of the help icon). From the monitor you can select File Explorer tab.

Comment: @YeLinAung Hi, yes that is what I'm trying to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> this is the Android Device Monitor in Android Studio and the file explorer tab should be there but is not.

Perhaps you accidentally closed it. I just ran the Android Device Monitor, from Android Studio 1.1, and the File Explorer tab appears as normal. However, as with the other tabs, it has an "x" in the tab to close it, and if you do that, it will no longer show up.

To make it appear again, choose Window > Show View from the Android Device Monitor main menu, and choose Android > File Explorer in the tree of available views. Click OK, and the tab should reappear.

Comment: Hi @CommonsWare , there is no Show View option in the Window menu on this version. http://i.stack.imgur.com/APMwI.png also there is no option to close the File Explorer tab, you can hide the tabs but a small icon still appears at the right and you just have to click on them to show the tab again.

Comment: @JavierGonzalez: You are looking at the Android Studio window. The Android Device Monitor is a separate window, opened via Tools > Android > Android Device Monitor. Then, choose Window > Show View **from the Android Device Monitor main menu**.

Comment: I saw now that another windows opens when you open it that way, the problem was that it didn't change the focus to it but to the one that in the screenshot so I didn't notice, thank you very much for your help