# My logcat shows TLUI instead of app in the logcat warning messages

Tags: android, android-studio, logcat

In every app I am writing since last week, this warning with TLUI shows up in my logcat:

```
12-31 04:02:27.108 25942-25942/com.example.user.threads W/System:ClassLoaderreferenced unknown path: /data/app/com.example.user.threads-1/lib/arm
12-31 04:02:27.694 25942-25942/com.example.user.threads W/System:ClassLoaderreferenced unknown path: /data/app/com.example.user.threads-1/lib/arm
12-31 04:02:27.913 25942-25942/com.example.user.threads W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
12-31 04:02:27.923 25942-25942/com.example.user.threads W/zipro: Error opening archive /data/TLUI/com.example.user.threads: I/O Error
12-31 04:02:27.924 25942-25942/com.example.user.threads W/zipro: Error opening archive /system/TLUI/com.example.user.threads: I/O Error
12-31 04:02:28.256 25942-25976/com.example.user.threads W/libEGL: [ANDROID_RECORDABLE] format: 1
```

(com.example.user.threads is my package name)

I don't know what TLUI means. There's nothing of that name in my PC directories. I googled and searched here also for it, but no result came up.

Also, this term always comes up with I/O errors. I reinstalled Android Studio but it's still the same. Where is the problem?

Comment: The problem is on your Android device / Emulator, not on your PC or in Android Studio.

Comment: how do i see this directory in the phone? I searched from Settings for TLUI but no result.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17628670/file-explorer-in-android-studio

Comment: Thanks. But I still can't find anything called TLUI. And the `data` folder is not expanding at all in the file explorer. I click on the expand icon beside it and then the icon appears again.

Comment: If your phone is not rooted you can not explore it like this

Answer (score 0):

I see that in the logcat entries when installing my own apk as well. There is a directory `/system/TLUI` which, on my BLU phones, only contains a folder `appicon` with two png icons.

But, the `libandroidfw.so` on the phone looks for archives under both `/data/TLUI` and `/system/TLUI` when installing a package using `adb` (and also, presumably, `pm`). It's a harmless warning; it found and installed the package; but that's why you're seeing the message.